# ethereum.org - buy/sell example unclear

Tags: address.transfer

From the buy/sell example on [ethereum.org](https://www.ethereum.org/token):

```
function buy() payable returns (uint amount){
    amount = msg.value / buyPrice;                    // calculates the amount
    _transfer(this, msg.sender, amount);
    return amount;
}

function sell(uint amount) returns (uint revenue){
    require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= amount);         // checks if the sender has enough to sell
    balanceOf[this] += amount;                        // adds the amount to owner's balance
    balanceOf[msg.sender] -= amount;                  // subtracts the amount from seller's balance
    revenue = amount * sellPrice;
    msg.sender.transfer(revenue);                     // sends ether to the seller: it's important to do this last to prevent recursion attacks
    Transfer(msg.sender, this, amount);               // executes an event reflecting on the change
    return revenue;                                   // ends function and returns
}
```

In the `sell` function, I understand that Ether is transferred from the contract to the caller via:

```
msg.sender.transfer(revenue)
```

But in the `buy` function, I see nothing equivalent to ensure that Ether is transferred from the caller to the contract.

So how exactly does that take place? Does the keyword `payable` have anything to do with it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send ether *to* a contract, you invoke one of its `payable` functions by sending some ether together with the transaction.

For example: `myContract.buy({}, { from: myAddress, value: someAmountInWei })`

The amount received can then be seen in `msg.value`. No action is needed inside the contract to receive ether, the amount is automatically added to the account of the contract once the call finishes successfully (Note: if a function isn't `payable`, calling it with non-zero ether will fail).

`address.transfer()` is used to send ether *from* a contract to some other address (the caller of the function in the case of `msg.sender.transfer()`).

Comment: So the `payable` keyword does not only "have something to do with it", but is also the actual trigger which ensures that Ether is transferred into the contract... Am I right?

Comment: `payable` is just a flag that allows ether to be sent together with the function call. Without it the function automatically rejects the call if it has any ether value. It's just a safety measure to prevent accidental payments to functions that don't do anything with the received amount.

Comment: OK, but what exactly makes the amount to be "automatically added to the account of the contract once the call finishes successfully"? I mean, is that true for every function (declared `payable`) which is called with `{msg.value > 0}`?

Comment: A contract is "called" by sending a *transaction* to it. It's the same kind of transaction that you use to transfer ether from user A to user B, the network takes care of transferring the ether regardless of who user B is. Only in case user B is a contract, the EVM will additionally execute its code that further interprets the payload in the transaction (the function name and its arguments).